# I need a 2nd pair of eyes to look at my code, having trouble figuring it out on my own

Tags: reactjs, react-class-based-component

I'm having trouble figuring out why for some reason the my application sets isError to true... (the error is being caught even when the login is successful => when i refresh the page everything is ok). I am not sure if I explained it right, I'll be here to clear everything if something is unclear

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {NavLink, Navigate, redirect} from "react-router-dom";
import {Button, Form, Grid, Segment, Message} from "semantic-ui-react";
import AuthContext from "../AuthContext/AuthContext";
import {fitZoneApi} from "../../repository/FitZoneApi";
import {handleLogError} from "../Helpers/Helpers";

class Login extends Component {
    static contextType = AuthContext

    brojac = null;


    state = {
        username: '',
        password: '',
        isLoggedIn: false,
        isError: false
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        const Auth = this.context
        const isLoggedIn = Auth.userIsAuthenticated()
        this.setState({ isLoggedIn })
        // this.brojac= setTimeout(() => this.refresh(), 2000 )
    }

    handleInputChange = (e, { name, value }) => {
        this.setState({ [name]: value })
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        const { username, password } = this.state
        if (!(username && password)) {
            this.setState({ isError: true })
            return
        }

        fitZoneApi.authenticate(username, password)
            .then(response => {
                const { name } = response.data
                const authdata = window.btoa(username + ':' + password)
                const user = { name, authdata }

                const Auth = this.context
                Auth.userLogin(user)

                this.setState({
                    username: '',
                    password: '',
                    isLoggedIn: true,
                    isError: false
                })

            })
            .catch(error => {
                handleLogError(error)
                this.setState({ isError: true })
                // this.delay(5000)
                // this.refresh()
                this.brojac= setTimeout(() => this.refresh(), 2000 )
            })
    }

    refresh = () => window.location.reload(true)


    render() {
        const { isLoggedIn, isError } = this.state
        if (isLoggedIn) {
            return <Navigate to={'/'} />
        } else {
            return (
                <Grid textAlign='center'>
                    <Grid.Column style={{ maxWidth: 450 }}>
                        <Form size='large' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                            <Segment>
                                <Form.Input
                                    fluid
                                    autoFocus
                                    name='username'
                                    icon='user'
                                    iconPosition='left'
                                    placeholder='Username'
                                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                                />
                                <Form.Input
                                    fluid
                                    name='password'
                                    icon='lock'
                                    iconPosition='left'
                                    placeholder='Password'
                                    type='password'
                                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                                />
                                <Button color='blue' fluid size='large'>Login</Button>
                            </Segment>
                        </Form>
                        <Message>{`Don't have already an account? `}
                            <a href='/signup' color='teal'>Sign Up</a>
                        </Message>
                        {isError && <Message negative>The username or password provided are incorrect!</Message>}
                    </Grid.Column>
                </Grid>
            )
        }
    }
}

export default Login;
```

here is the fitZoneApi.authenticate method

```
function authenticate(username, password) {
    return instance.post('/login', {username, password})
}
```

this is the handleError method

```
export const handleLogError = (error) => {
    if (error.response) {
        console.log(error.response.data);
    } else if (error.request) {
        console.log(error.request);
    } else {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
}
```

I've tried wrapping is the code like this but same results:

```
.catch(error => {
                handleLogError(error)
                if(error){
                this.setState({ isError: true })
                }
               
                // this.delay(5000)
                // this.refresh()
                this.brojac= setTimeout(() => this.refresh(), 2000 )
            }
```

Also I have the refresh method because my component does not update after submitting the form, 2nd reason is because I got tired of doing it manually => even if I enter the proper credentials, the app doesn't authenticate me unless I reload the page.
I am kinda new to this, be gentle please.... any help is appreciated <3 Much love